# writing a custom setup.exe suite installer

Tags: installation, windows-installer, suite

I've been tasked to create an installer that will handle and install multiple .msi files. I nearly went down the InstallShield route, but you need to Premier edition to create Suite installations, and to say you're paying almost £3000 doesn't even let you fully customise the UI.

For our last release I wrote a custom Setup.exe file which looks in the same folder that it is stored, for the msi files we wish to install, and then silently installs each one. It's pretty basic though, and we now need something more professional.

At the moment I've got 2 main options:

- Use WiX - This is free and seems to offer a lot of customisability. I'm not too sure yet what exactly it can do, and it will take a bit of time to learn.
- I can expand upon what I already have and build my own installer that allows the user to pick which features/components they want to install and which they don't. I would prefer this if I could get the installer to download the required msi files from a server, install them, then delete them. I just don't want to have to include a separate folder full of msi files with the main setup download. Would this be possible without TOO much effort? Also, using this would I be able to add a single program to the Add/Remove Programs menu?

Any ideas welcome :)

Comment: I'd love to hear more about what further UI customization you would want from InstallShield. Some of it may be possible, but there are a lot of gaps we're still looking to fill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend checking out the features of Burn in WiX 3.6. You can create a bootstrapper and it has the capability to download your installation packages from a server. You can fully customize it or use the standard bootstrapper application. You can use your current .msis as well. You don't have to convert all of your .msis to WiX to use the bootstrapper functionality.

I'd recommend reading [this blog post](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2012/6/25/B-is-for-Bundle-and-thats-good-enough-for-me) by Rob Mensching.

Answer (score 0):

How effort free it is depends on how complex your set ups are, the interdependencies and their pre-requisites.

For instance you want to install product X, but it needs a database server installed, which need a .net framework upgrade, which need reboots..

Wix is for creating msi's so it would only be a help if you wanted to create an msi could manage the install of several apps.

Comment: The main feature of WiX 3.6 is Burn, which is a bootstrapper/chainer.

Comment: MSI's *can't* (technically or properly ) handle the installation of several MSI's because of mutex's that exist within WindowsInstaller.

Comment: They can handle msm's which is effectively the same thing, however neither is designed for this sort of choice.

Comment: The main feature of Wix is, it's not that binary crap tools like Wise give you. Once you have an xml file, writing something to twiddle with it, is simply a question of how mad you want to go wth teh feature set.

Answer (score 0):

WiX 3.6 is still a beta project and Burn is still a work in progress.  Truthfully InstallShield Suite installers are pretty new and still a work in progress as well.

Before you get all freaked out over the cost of InstallShield, you need to decide exactly what your setup.exe needs to be able to do.  Then you need to do a feature gap analysis between InstallShield and WiX and come up with labor estimates for rolling your own, doing it in WiX and doing it in InstallShield.

It certain situations the off the shelf tools aren't mature enough and it makes sense to roll your own.  ( Think MS SQL Server,  Office,  Visual Studio )  but for most line of business applications you probably just need to pick the tool that gets you closest to where you need to be.

Comment: Wasn't me that down voted you, but I've got to say as soon as you get (or more to the point have to go) outside of one of these tools comfort zones, they turn into a total nightmare. The tipping point for write your own installer versus off the shelf IMO is how likely is that (or more probably are those) scenarios.

Comment: I can't really agree. I've been writing installers for a living for 16 years and have used just about every tool out there. Sure, InstallShield does have it it's warts... but the reality is most people run into problems because they don't bother to learn the underlying Windows Installer (which also has it's warts).  Eventually abstractions leak and things fail and if you don't fully understand how it actually works your in the dark trying to fix it.

Comment: All in all, when you really know this stuff, you'd be suprised just how valuable a tool like InstallShield is. For example, I can crank out complex installs such as multiple instance n-Tier asp.net / sql server installs with full configuration settings UI experience in just a matter of hours.  I do a lot of consulting and my labor estimates are typically 1/10th of my peers.

Comment: Not knocking your game mate. Nobody would be happier than me if I could bat installation issues over to someone else. :(

Comment: What I mean is most people who do installs don't specialize in it and don't want to do it. Then they blame the tool when it doesn't go well.

Answer (score 0):

For something that needs to be a little bit more professional than your own custom setup.exe, with less of a learning curve than WiX and Burn, and less of a pain on your wallet than InstallShield - I would suggest [MSI Factory](http://www.indigorose.com/products/msi-factory/), not for MSI Factory (it would speed up your WiX learning though) but for the bootstrapper thats included.

The learning curve is less than Burn, and there's a 90 day trial so you can see if its good enough for you.

InstallShield will let you customise the installation interface, and for that hefty price tag you get support and maintenance (*very* useful when you're ramping up from scratch).

What you save on up front cost with InstallShield, you'll invest in terms of time with WiX - so you really need to do a cost/benefit analysis and figure out how much your time is worth. InstallShield is just as powerful as WiX when you really start to understand Windows Installer and what's under the hood. Many commercial developers will use elements from both depending on individual project requirements.